# Problema para adicionar conteúdo em ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

Eu tenho uma classe abstrata animal, que felino e canino herdam dela, e tenho uma classe cliente que possui 2 *arrays*, um para adicionar felinos e outro para caninos.

Porém na hora de adicionar pela classe executável o felino no *array* em um objeto cliente, fica marcando erro na linha.

Aqui está meu código:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class App {

    Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);
    public static ArrayList<Cliente> clientes;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println("|||||Clínica Veterinária 1.0|||||\n\n");

        int opcao = 0;
        switch(opcao){
        case 1:
            String nome = null;
                        String cpf = null;
            clientes.add(new Cliente(nome, cpf));
            break;
        case 2:
            String nomeCat = null; double pesoCat = 0.0; int idadeCat = 0;
            clientes.adicionaFelino(nomeCat, pesoCat, idadeCat);
            //a IDE marca erro nesta linha acima
                        break;
        default:    
        return null;
        }
}
```

Classe Animal

```
public abstract class Animal {

    protected double peso;

    public double calculaAnestesia(){
        double ml = 0.0;
        ml = peso*0.3;
        return ml;
    }

}
```

Classe Felino

```
public class Felino extends Animal {

    private String nome;
    private int idade;

    public Felino(String nome, int idade, double peso){
        this.nome = nome;
        this.peso = peso;
        this.idade = idade;

    }

    public String getNome() {
        return nome;
    }

    public void setNome(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
    }

    public int getIdade() {
        return idade;
    }

    public void setIdade(int idade) {
        this.idade = idade;
    }

    public double getPeso(){
        return peso;
    }

    public void setPeso(double peso){
        this.peso = peso;
    }

}
```

Classe Canino

```
public class Canino extends Animal{

    private String nome;
    private int idade;

    public Canino(String nome, int idade, double peso){
        this.peso = peso;
        this.nome = nome;
        this.idade = idade;

    }

    public String getNome() {
        return nome;
    }

    public void setNome(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
    }

    public int getIdade() {
        return idade;
    }

    public void setIdade(int idade) {
        this.idade = idade;
    }

    public double getPeso(){
        return peso;
    }

    public void setPeso(double peso){
        this.peso = peso;
    }
}
```

Classe cliente

```
import java.util.ArrayList;


public class Cliente {

    private String nome, cpf;
    private ArrayList<Animal> animais;

    public Cliente(String nome, String cpf){
        this.nome = nome;
        this.cpf = cpf;
    }

    public String getNome() {
        return nome;
    }

    public void setNome(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
    }

    public String getCpf() {
        return cpf;
    }

    public void setCpf(String cpf) {
        this.cpf = cpf;
    }

    public ArrayList<Felino> adicionaFelino(String nomeGato, int idade, double peso){
        animais.add(new Felino(nomeGato, idade, peso));
        return null;
    }

    public String adicionaCanino(String nomeCao, int idade, double peso){
        animais.add(new Canino(nomeCao, idade, peso));
        return("animal adicionado");
    }


}
```

Comment: Adicione o erro e todas as classes informadas na pergunta.

Comment: Já de cara me parece que nem o problema, nem o código apresentado fazem sentido. O código a gente até consegue ajudar, mas se o problema já estiver todo errado, não tem muito o que fazer.

Comment: O erro é de tipo, você está passando um double onde se recebe um int. `adicionaFelino(String nomeGato, int idade, double peso)` tem que passar nesta ordem, e você está passando `clientes.adicionaFelino(nomeCat, pesoCat, idadeCat);` onde pesoCat é double. Você inverteu pesoCat com idadeCat. O correto deveria ser: `clientes.adicionaFelino(nomeCat, idadeCat, pesoCat);`

Comment: Ainda não solucionou, o que fica sublinhado é o adicionaFelino na linha clientes.adicionafelino(nomeCat, idadeCat, pesoCat);

Comment: `clientes` é um ArrayList, não é seu objeto Cliente. Logo, esse método `adicionaFelino` não existe nele.

Comment: Pois é, agora que fui me ligar que tenho que percorrer que fazer um "getCliente" ora encontrar ele na lista e adicionar o animal ao cliente correto, obrigado pela ajuda diego.

Comment: A resposta resolveu o seu problema? Acha que pode aceitá-la agora? @MiltonTeixeira Veja o [tour] para entender como funciona. Ajudaria muito indicar para todo mundo que a solução foi útil e satisfatória para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo (quando tiver 15 pontos).

Answer (score 2):

O código tinhas vários erros, alguns sintáticos bem básicos (fora a desorganização. Eu corrigi para compilar. Mas ainda tem outros problemas e ele não faz o menor sentido. As classes não estão muito boas, mas nada terrível, mas o `main()` está bem confuso e só funciona em circunstância bem específica. A solução que eu dei não é ideal, foi só para poder compilar.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;
 
class App {
 
    Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);
    public static ArrayList<Cliente> clientes;
 
    public static void main(String[] args) {
 
        System.out.println("|||||Clínica Veterinária 1.0|||||\n\n");
 
        int opcao = 0;
        switch(opcao){
        case 1:
            String nome = null;
            String cpf = null;
            clientes.add(new Cliente(nome, cpf));
            break;
        case 2:
            String nomeCat = null; double pesoCat = 0.0; int idadeCat = 0;
            clientes.get(0).adicionaFelino(nomeCat, idadeCat, pesoCat);
            break;
        default:    
            return;
        }
    }
}
 
abstract class Animal {
 
    protected double peso;
 
    public double calculaAnestesia(){
        double ml = 0.0;
        ml = peso*0.3;
        return ml;
    }
}
 
class Felino extends Animal {
 
    private String nome;
    private int idade;
 
    public Felino(String nome, int idade, double peso){
        this.nome = nome;
        this.peso = peso;
        this.idade = idade;
 
    }
 
    public String getNome() {
        return nome;
    }
 
    public void setNome(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
    }
 
    public int getIdade() {
        return idade;
    }
 
    public void setIdade(int idade) {
        this.idade = idade;
    }
 
    public double getPeso(){
        return peso;
    }
 
    public void setPeso(double peso){
        this.peso = peso;
    }
}
 
class Canino extends Animal{
 
    private String nome;
    private int idade;
 
    public Canino(String nome, int idade, double peso){
        this.peso = peso;
        this.nome = nome;
        this.idade = idade;
 
    }
 
    public String getNome() {
        return nome;
    }
 
    public void setNome(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
    }
 
    public int getIdade() {
        return idade;
    }
 
    public void setIdade(int idade) {
        this.idade = idade;
    }
 
    public double getPeso(){
        return peso;
    }
 
    public void setPeso(double peso){
        this.peso = peso;
    }
}
 
class Cliente {
 
    private String nome, cpf;
    private ArrayList<Animal> animais;
 
    public Cliente(String nome, String cpf){
        this.nome = nome;
        this.cpf = cpf;
    }
 
    public String getNome() {
        return nome;
    }
 
    public void setNome(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
    }
 
    public String getCpf() {
        return cpf;
    }
 
    public void setCpf(String cpf) {
        this.cpf = cpf;
    }
 
    public ArrayList<Felino> adicionaFelino(String nomeGato, int idade, double peso){
        animais.add(new Felino(nomeGato, idade, peso));
        return null;
    }
 
    public String adicionaCanino(String nomeCao, int idade, double peso){
        animais.add(new Canino(nomeCao, idade, peso));
        return("animal adicionado");
    }
}
```

Veja ["funcionando" no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/bzdr8d). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/fvjdoiys-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Array/AddAbstract.java).

A chamada do método `adicionaFelino()` estava errada porque invertia os argumentos e porque estava tentando fazer na lista de clientes e não no cliente específico. Usei o `get(0)` para pegar o cliente específico e adicionar o felino. Isto está errado, mas o resto também está. Agora tem uma base melhor para ir consertando os problemas. Ainda pode fazer outras perguntas mais específicas.

Comment: é eu demorei a perceber que estava tentando adicionar o animal na lista de clientes e não em um objeto, estou trabalhando nisso agora, e muito obrigado amigo, a sua ajuda foi BEM esclarecedora.

Answer (score 2):

O erro está nesse trecho:

```
    switch(opcao){
        case 1:
            String nome = null;
            String cpf = null;
            clientes.add(new Cliente(nome, cpf));
            break;
        case 2:
            String nomeCat = null; double pesoCat = 0.0; int idadeCat = 0;
            clientes.adicionaFelino(nomeCat, pesoCat, idadeCat);
            //a IDE marca erro nesta linha acima
            break;
        default:    
            return null;
    }
```

Acontece que você está chamando o método `adicionaFelino` em uma lista, mas esse método só existe dentro de um objeto cliente. Você terá que chamar esse método no objeto cliente. Exemplo:

```
Cliente cliente = new CLiente(nome, cpf);

String nomeCat = null; 
double pesoCat = 0.0; 
int idadeCat = 0;

cliente.adicionaFelino(nomeCat, pesoCat, idadeCat);

clientes.add(cliente);
```

Esse seria o funcionamento correto para adicionar um felino em um cliente e um cliente na lista de clientes. Não tenho noção da regra que está desenvolvendo, mas acredito que terá que alterar seu código main pois não está lógicamente de acordo.